How to create custom element type
i have a new project multisite and multilanguage, i need to create a custom Element Type to manage Custom Products (purchasable).
I read many times the docs (https://craftcms.com/docs/5.x/extend/element-types.html), i search on Google and with AI, i tried to copy code from plugins but i cannot undestand how to create the element type, my question is not only for the specific class, but for everithig, every steps, from registrations to controller and fieldLayout, can someone explain me every step and/or paste here him Element Type with comments so that I can clearly understand each function?
I create the classes but many functions not work, so i need to undestand everithings.
Thanks in advise
